# AJAX File Upload without refresh, refreshes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, upload

I have a form where I want to user to upload a file but the page cannot refresh. But with the current script, it does.

JS:

```
$(function () { // Inserts data into SQL table without refreshing
    $('#mailattachment').on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'functions/glist-MailAttachment.php',
        contentType: attr('enctype', "multipart/form-data"),
        data: $('#mailattachment').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if(response == 8 || response == 9){

            }       
            evt.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Add Attachment</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="mailattachment">
            <div class="col-md-12 clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select File</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </form>
```

The upload works fine if I set only the action of the form and not the ID. But I've used this JS to handle my PHP scripts for adding content to a SQL database. Now I've seen that you have to add this line:
contentType: attr('enctype', "multipart/form-data"),

But that makes it refresh and NOT upload the file.

So my question is, what's wrong with the JS?

Comment: If the file uploads, you are doing it through form submit. Ajax call is missed. As note, you can't use ajax to upload files (but you can use base64 encoding)

Comment: `attr` its incorrect. You mean `$(this).attr('enctype', "multipart/form-data")`. Why you are changing the attribute on runtime? And also assigning it to `contentType` property doesn't make sense which is totally incorrect.

Comment: I'm was aware of that @RahilWazir but couldn't find a way to fix it. Used jQuery Form which fixed my problem!